# Кэшировать изображение по ссылке и отправить POST запрос с этим изображением.

Tags: python-3.x, request, urllib

Есть ссылка на изображение/документ.
Как на python3 реализовать:
Получить изображение, не сохраняя его на комп, и сделать запрос с этим изображением?
Собственно интересует как привязать картинку к переменной?

```
import requests

img_url = "http://site.com/image1337.jpg"

# как получить?
img_cached = ???

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
    # подготовить полученное изображение к отправке
    'img': ('some_img.jpg', img_cached),
}

response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/',headers=headers, files=files, auth=('login', 'password'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP не поддерживает запросы, чтобы данные между двумя удалёнными серверами передавались, не загружая их локально. Есть протоколы (scp, gridftp), которые позволяют файл с одного сервера на другой перекачать, не загружая данные на клиент.

Простейший вариант: целиком загрузить и целиком же отправить данные:

```
requests.post(destination_url, data=requests.get(source_url).content)
```

Можно по частям скачивать с одного сервера и отправлять на другой сервер, не дожидаясь пока целиком скачается файл:

```
requests.post(destination_url, data=requests.get(source_url, stream=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
# используем модуль io.BytesIO
#from io import BytesIO

img_url = "http://site.com/image1337.jpg"

#  получаем так
# img_cached = BytesIO(bytes(requests.get(url).content)).read()

# а лучше так
# спасибо @gil9red
img_cached = requests.get(url).content


headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
}

files = {
    # все уже готово
    'img': ('some_img.jpg', img_cached),
}

response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/',headers=headers, files=files, auth=('login', 'password'))
```

Comment: `bytes(requests.get(url).content)` излишний,, т.к. content уже bytes, достаточно: `requests.get(url).content`. Еще... зачем у объекта BytesIO вызывать read()? read ведь байты возвращает, т.е. вы получаете массив байтов, на массиве байт создаете байты (одно и тоже будет), после оборачиваете массив байт в BytesIO и сразу же возвращает массив байт. По идеи, достаточно будет: `img_cached = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)`, но если вариант с `read` сработал, тогда и: `img_cached = requests.get(url).content`